# I am having troubles with an IF-statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which works very good, but when i tried implementing a small thing it didnt go as planned. The code looks like this:

```
 'Bredd byggnad
Dim clValue1 As String
clValue1 = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").Range("C10").Value)
If clValue1 = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en bredd på byggnaden"
    Exit Sub
End If
If clValue1 = "0" Then
    MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en bredd på byggnaden som är större än 0"
    Exit Sub
End If
If CLng(clValue1) < 0 Then
    MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en bredd på byggnaden som är större än 0"
    Exit Sub
End If

If InStr(1, clValue1, ".") <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Denna cell får inte innehålla en punkt, ändra det till ett komma."
    Exit Sub
End If

'Längd byggnad
Dim clValue2 As String
clValue2 = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").Range("C11").Value)
If clValue2 = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en längd på byggnaden"
    Exit Sub
End If
If clValue2 = "0" Then
    MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en längd på byggnaden som är större än 0"
    Exit Sub
End If
If CLng(clValue2) < 0 Then
    MsgBox "Var vänligen ange en längd på11 byggnaden som är större än 0"
    Exit Sub
End If

If InStr(1, clValue2, ".") <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Denna cell får inte innehålla en punkt, ändra det till ett komma."
    Exit Sub
End If

If clValue2 < clValue1 Then
    MsgBox "Längden på byggnaden måste vara större än bredden"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The problem occurs in the last if-statement:

```
If clValue2 < clValue1 Then
    MsgBox "Längden på byggnaden måste vara större än bredden"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

What I want it to do is to exit the sub if the value in cell C11 is less then the value in cell C10.

Would appreciate any kind of help.

/ Rinor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place the following before the `if` statement:

```
MsgBox "[" & clValue1 & "]"
MsgBox "[" & clValue2 & "]"
```

then you'll probably be able to *see* what the problem is. Take *particular* note of any spaces in those string variables as well.

There's a good chance that, being strings, you're confused by the fact that (for example) `11` is considered less than `2`, since it's using string ordering rather than numeric ordering.

If that *is* the case, you can probably fix it with something like a simple:

```
If CDbl(clValue2) < CDbl(clValue1) Then
```

Comment: Hi,I placed it and it only gave me the values of the cells. When value in C11 is 100 and value in C10 is 90 the code works good. But when The value in C11 is 110 and value in C10 is 90 the code wont work as I wrote it.

Comment: @RinorM: and what happens when you cast them to doubles as I suggested?

Comment: Hi paxdiablo. Your sudgestion worked fine, thank you. What does the CDbl-commando do?

Comment: @RinorM: it turns those strings back into numbers so that the comparison works more in line with what you want. It's similar to the `CStr` that you've already used to turn the cell contents into a string, but going back the other way. `CInt` is similar but gives an integer rather than a floating point number.

Answer (score 1):

The Less than operator "<" won't work with strings. Try converting them to Integers instead with CInt(clValue1).

Comment: Hi I tried the solution which paxdiablo helped me with:

If CDbl(clValue2) < CDbl(clValue1) Then

and it worked fine.

Thank you for your time :)